# THREE JS | Making some faces of a BufferGeometry transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I have two cubes being rendered on a single non-indexed buffer geometry. I want these cubes to be transparent so that you can see all sides of them at once. I want to do this using the "vertexAlphas" material property so that I can specify an alpha value for each face of the geometry via the color attribute.

Heres my code:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()

const vertices = getVertices()// gets array of vertices for the two cubes
const colors = getColors() // gets rgba values for the two cubes

geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(vertices), 3))
geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint8Array(colors)), 4))

geometry.attributes.color.normalized = true
geometry.computeVertexNormals()

const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ transparent: true, vertexColors: true, vertexAlphas: true })

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh)
```

This successfully makes the cubes transparent. However, the middle faces are only visible from one side.

Front side:
[image]

Back side:
[image]

I understand this is happening due to the depthWrite function. And could theoretically be solved if I set DepthWrite to false, but I want to have the ability to make one of the cubes opaque, so I can't do this. Is there a way to basically "bypass" depthWrite for the transparent faces (or do something that has the same effect)? So that no matter what angle the camera views the transparent faces from, everything behind them shows? I want to maintain the use of the vertex alpha property opposed to the use of grouping and multiple materials (to avoid multiple render calls).

Could a custom shader work? I have no idea how to write a custom shader, so before learning, It would be nice to know if that could even work. Thank You to anyone who can help!

Comment: all 6 sides of both cubes are showing, so you should be able to see the middle face no matter what. That also doesn't solve the problem of the faces being hidden once the camera moves to the opposite side.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue,

It was an issue with the normal vectors. Since the normal vector give the direction in which the face is "pointing", the opposite faces of the cube need to have opposite normal values since they "point" in opposite directions (for example, the top face needs a normal vector of {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1} and the bottom face needs a normal vector of {x: 0, y: 0, z: -1})

The reason why the faces were being hidden from one side only was because of the computeVertexNormals function. Since this function doesn't know I'm trying to compute the normals of a cube, it would give opposite faces the same normal values.

I took out that function and added the normal values manually, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a winding-order error in your custom geometry. All front-faces should have counterclockwise winding-order.